Orthanc Delete API CORS Issue in the Production
I am using the Orthanc API endpoints. While attempting to use the DELETE endpoint, I am encountering a CORS issue in production, despite having defined the DELETE method in the Nginx configuration. How can I resolve this?
Following is my Nginx Config file
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen  8050;

        location /orthanc/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8042;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            rewrite /orthanc(.*) $1 break;

            # Allow CORS
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

            # Preflight CORS check
            if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS,DELETE';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
                return 204;
            }
           
        }
    }
}


As I have defined the DELETE yet I am getting the CORS issue.
